# Why is $2^{n/2}(5/3)^n(\cos(n\pi/4)+\sin(n\pi/4))$ an alternate form of the complex number $(5/3)^n(1+i)^n$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I get to that point?

I am aware of the formula

$$z = r (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)$$

and that

$$z^n = r^n(\cos n\alpha+ i\sin n\alpha)$$

But I don't know how to get to what is in the title, particularly why is the angle $n\pi /4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$z = 1+i = \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) =  2^{1/2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$

Now use *de Moivre*:
$$z^n = 2^{n/2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$

And finally:

> $$\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n (1+i)^n = \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n z^n = 2^{n/2} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n \left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Holy crap am I dumb. Thank you... For some reason I couldn't realize this.